# Text Alignment w/ IE9 in Standards-Mode

Tags: css, html

Can someone help me vertically center text inside a div, consistently across browsers. In IE9 ONLY, text is one pixel closer to the top of the parent div. All other browsers render the text as expected.

Important: I'm using standards-mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Here's some example HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div style="width:100px; height:16px; font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; line-height:1.2; background-color:red; color:White; vertical-align:middle">
<div style="line-height:16px">XXXXXXXXXX</div></div>
```

Comment: Also tried this code, as Marc suggested.   <div style="width:100px; height:16px; font-size:13px; line-height:13px; font-family:Arial; background-color:red; color:White; padding-top:2px">
   XXXXXXXXXX
  </div>

Comment: Changing the doctype gives expected results, but nothing else. And i dont want to change the doctype for the site.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party. However, I came across a similar issue recently. After some digging about I came across this article: [Sub-pixel Fonts in IE9](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/11/03/sub-pixel-fonts-in-ie9.aspx).

I think this is directly responsible for the issues of font vertical alignment in IE9. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a fix as this is a forced option or customisable by the user (not likely to happen).

So it looks like the only solution is to increase the line-height as mentioned previously.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the following:

[CSS: Standard (dynamic) way to centralize an element in the y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421990/css-standard-way-to-centralize-an-element-in-the-y-axis/5422667#5422667)

There are some useful references that will probably still apply to IE9.

**Based on your code**: you are setting the line-height in more than one place.  Try removing the `line-height:16px` property in your inner div, in fact, get rid of the inner div since vertical-align will only affect inline elements.

Also, make sure your container height is big enough to hold the text (1.2*13) otherwise you may get into issues related to different fonts or different default font-sizes across browsers.

Probably what is happening is that 1.2*13 = 15.6, and depending how the browser rounds off floating point numbers, that could account for a 1 pixel shift.  Set line-height to 16px instead of 1.2 and see if that works.

**Second Try**:

```
.outer {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serf;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 5.0;
}
```

applied to:

```
<div class="outer">XXXXXXXXXX</div>
```

If anything will fix this, make the line-height large enough so that there is some space above/below the lettering.  Set the container height to `auto` and let the line-height control the height of the container.

Comment: Try the above code in IE9 and then in another browser.  Making the changes you suggested do not have any effect on the issue I have raised.  I'd post images, but stackoverflow will not let me.  Changing the doctype gives expected results, but nothing else.  And i dont want to change the doctype for the site.

Comment: Are you on a Mac or PC?  The doctype is good, gives you strict mode, so keep it that way.  Are you using any css reset script?

Comment: PC.  There is no CSS on the page other than what I've provided.

Comment: Try the following fiddle and let me know how it works in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/pdKHP/

Comment: Same thing.  I also changed your css to use a line-height of 16px and the same problem exists.  Looks great in everything except IE 9.

Comment: So the problem exists regardless of the value of line-height?

Comment: I am stumped! IE9 is probably calculating the line-height slightly differently than the other browsers, could be a bug.  And you said it looks ok in IE8?

Comment: That is it for now, sorry could not crack this one, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to this question here:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/css-53/text-alignment-w-ie9-standards-mode-745359.html

I had the same problem with the 1px off text rendering, and it would only appear with font size 13px in IE9.

adding the css style

```
    {
      height: 16px;
      line-height:16.99px;
    }
```

to the surrounding div fixed the problem for me on IE7-9, FF and Chrome on Windows.